# Is is more performant to use a singleton Executor service or function-specific executor service?

Tags: java, spring, graphql

What I'm really trying to figure out is how to think about this question, or get some insight from those with more experience in this field.

Say this is a singleton class in a web service, like a graphql datafetcher. Which is more performant at scale: the first or the second? Or will there be any performance difference?

```
public class FooBarClass {
    public List<Bar> getSomeStuff() {
            List<Bar> bar = new ArrayList<Bar>;

            final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            //Get the stuff in multithreaded way.
            threadpool.shutdown();
            return bar;
        };
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class FooBarClass {

    final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 

    public List<Bar> getSomeStuff() {
            //...
            //Get the stuff using the executor service.
            return bar;
        };
    }


}
```

What I have found is that using the executor service definitely speeds up the code. We are doing a batch-like fetch but we need to do single fetches for some reasons, so did all the fetches async.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends.

Suppose every service has its own pool of 10 threads, and you have say 50 services, you have 500 threads total.

When you have a large number of threads (not that 500 is necessarily large), it is quite possible that most of them are idle most of the time, which is reasonably wasteful. Threads have overhead and context switching between them is relatively slow.

If each service has its own pool, there might be a situation where one service's pool is completely maxed out, with a huge queue of tasks, while other executors are completely idle. It would be better in those cases the pools could cooperate and share resources. This is a case for services sharing a common pool.

Isolation from other services is sometimes good though. Tasks have different priorities, and you don't want your trivial low-priority jobs consuming all your threads, leaving high priority ones to wait in a queue. This is a case for each service having its own pool.

In practice, I find the best approach is somewhere in the middle. Some services are high priority and I don't want those to be affected by what's going on elsewhere in the app. I give those types of services a dedicated thread pool. Other services are not high priority, and I don't care whether there might be small delays between task submission and executions. For those, I make them share a common thread pool.